# XSLT for-each statement not iterating proper amount of times

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having trouble with my XSLT for-each statements. When I run the XML through the XSLT, it only comes up with the first iteration of the list, and then stops. It doesn't post the values either. Here is the XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template>
    <L>
        <Q>Hey</Q>
        <Q>There</Q>
        <Q>Thank
            <R>You</R>
            <R>For</R>
            <R>The</R>
            <R>Help</R>
            <R>I</R>
            <R>Hope</R>
            <R>This</R>
        </Q>
        <Q> will work!
        </Q>
    </L>
</template>
```

here is the xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/template/L">
<html>
<body>
<ul><xsl:for-each select="Q">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="Q"/>
        <ul><xsl:for-each select="R">
            <li><xsl:value-of select="R"/></li>
        </xsl:for-each></ul>
    </li>
</xsl:for-each></ul> 
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output should look like an unordered list with another list embedded inside of it (the R tags are the embedded list values). It should look something like this:

- Hey
- There
- Thank

  - You
  - For
  - The
  - Help
  - I
  - Hope
  - This
- will work!

here

Comment: I am guessing this is just a typo in your question, but your XSLT is not well-formed, as your `xsl:for-each` tags are all self-closed (For example `<xsl:for-each select="Q"/>`). Also, can you edit your question to show the expected output in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Tim! The xslt file iterates correctly now, but it is not posting the values. I edited the question to show what the expected output should be. From playing around with the code, I have found that I can get values before for-each loops, but not after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/template/L">
  <html>
     <body>
        <ul>
           <xsl:for-each select="Q">
              <li>
                 <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                 <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="R">
                       <li>
                          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                       </li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                 </ul>
              </li>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
     </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**:
When you are in the context of `<xsl:for-each select="Q">`, the instruction `<xsl:value-of select="Q"/>` does not select anything (unless the `Q` element has another `Q` element as a child). Similarly, `<xsl:value-of select="R"/>` does not select anything when the context is `<xsl:for-each select="R">`.

This is in addition to the comment regarding self-closing the `xsl:for-each` element.

---

> the sub-list should only be created if the `<Q>` tag has a `<R>` tag child

I don't see what difference it makes (in HTML), but if you want, you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="/template/L">
  <html>
     <body>
        <ul>
           <xsl:for-each select="Q">
              <li>
                 <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                 <xsl:if test="R">
                     <ul>
                        <xsl:for-each select="R">
                           <li>
                              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                           </li>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                     </ul>                  
                 </xsl:if>
              </li>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
     </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: - Hey
       -Hey
- There
       -There
- Thank
       -Thank You For The Help I Hope This
- will work!
      -will work!                                                                                                is the result of the code. thank you for helping me! I am trying to eliminate the duplicates. the sub-list should only be created if the <Q> tag has a <R> tag child

Comment: @LelandWoodward No, that is **not** the result of the code I have posted.

Comment: Thanks Michael! The addition of the <xsl:if test="R"> worked perfectly!